# Aix + Apache not serving static files as uploaded

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, aix

Ok, bear with me, this is kind of hard to explain.

I have an AIX server (5.3.9.0) that is running apache 2.2.11. With static files (css, html), I can upload a file to the server, and when I call it, either directly or not, it doesn't show me the updated file, for at least 10 minutes. Then it appears. The apache modules mod_cache, mod_mem_cache and mod_disk_cache are installed, but I have disabled the cache in the httpd.conf file (passes syntax check as well), and it continues to be a problem.

Any ideas what I need to change? The server loads php and cgi files perfectly fine.

Comment: Just after posting we found the fix... in your httpd.conf file add:

EnableSendfile Off'

Comment: You should post your fix as an answer then come back in a couple of days and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Setting [EnableSendfile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#enablesendfile) to off in httpd.conf  e.g.

```
Enablesendfile Off
```

solved the problem.